# Key to Value / Value to Key in java

Tags: java, spring, apache

I want to get the key from value / and value from key ,can anyone help to do in better way ? or can we implement the below code using java enum or spring or apache enumutils or java generic ?

Note : I used to get string from frond end(.jsp) and i want to store store this value into database table as integer.

```
Frond end  Database table
Admin   ---   1
Manager ---   2   
Employee ---  3
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class   MyRole  {

    static HashMap<Integer,String> result= new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    static{
    result.put(1,"Admin");
    result.put(2,"Manager");
    }

    public static int getId(String role){
          Integer key=-1;
          for(Map.Entry entry: result.entrySet()){
                if(role.equals(entry.getValue())){
                    key = (Integer) entry.getKey();
                    break; 
                }
            }

      return key;

    }
    public static String getRole(int id){
        return result.get(id);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String result=MyRole.getRole(1);
        System.out.println("role name"+result);
        int roleId=MyRole.getId("Admin");
        System.out.println("role id "+roleId);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: Looks like a typical hibernate usecase... http://hibernate.org/

Comment: No problem with the current one.. want to minimize the line of code with the help of  spring or apache common utils api or enum or generic.

Comment: @VasanthDha: Then, maybe ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good idea.

Comment: Before you post there check their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and/or [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EnumUtils

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils;

import java.util.Optional;

public enum MyRole  {

    Admin(1),
    Manager(2);

    private int id;

    MyRole(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static int getId(String role){
        return Optional.ofNullable(EnumUtils.getEnum(MyRole.class, role)).map(MyRole::id).orElse(-1);
    }

    public static String getRole(int id){
        return EnumUtils.getEnumList(MyRole.class).stream().filter(r -> r.id == id).map(MyRole::name).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String result=MyRole.getRole(1);
        System.out.println("role name"+result);
        int roleId=MyRole.getId("Admin");
        System.out.println("role id "+roleId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Holadola.